# after configurable product being imported, on editing it shows attributes to make configurable(like you are creating first time)

Tags: magento-1.9, import, importexport

I have successfully imported a configurable product with all it's simple products. But on editing the configurable product from backend, it shows global attributes to make configurable product like the first time i'm creating.

Below is the screenshot of what i see on editing the already imported product.
[image]

Did i miss anything important to import configurable products ?

Note: I'm in magento version 1.9.2 & using CSV file to import/export.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your imported csv.There may be a field missing which relates to the configurable attribute.On missing of that value in the csv it is again asking to select the attribute.

Hope you got me.

Comment: what might be those fields ? like related to configurable.

Answer (score 0):

For importing a configurable product along with its associated (simple) products. In the product CSV you will have to add an extra attribute which are not mentioned in above comments. Also after exporting CSV Magento will not add the attributes in CSV.

First create your CSV file with all data and then at the end of CSV file add these attributes:

- configurable_attributess
- simples_skus

**Uses of the attributes:**

- `configurable_attributes` : If you have size attribute then for all simple products add the size in this attribute column and for configurable product add name size, like the screen shot below:
  [image]
- `simples_skus`: In the attribute column left all the simple products blank and for configurable product add all the simple sku's separated by comma. Same as the screen shot below:
  [image]

Now when the CSV is uploaded the configurable product will get uploaded with its configurable options(color, size etc) and all the associated(simple) products will be added.

Hope it help someone!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. The main thing is that you have to import the simple products first, then the configurable products. **Dataflow Profiles** are the old way and have been superseded by the **ImportExport** module. Unfortunately that module lacks abilities like exporting only a certain type of product. The profiles, on the other hand, can't properly export/import configurable products.

So I ended up using a mixture of both. Here's my whole process:

- I copied `/media/catalog/products/*` from the source store to `/media/import/` in the target store.
- I used the **Dataflow Profiles** to export **only** the simple products and re-imported those in the target store.
- As **Dataflow Profiles** don't handle configurable products I used the regular export function (the ImportExport module) to export all products (as you can not selectively export configurable only) and imported this file in the target store.
- If the import gets stuck on "Please wait", just split the file into smaller pieces and import those separately. Just make sure you don't split up in the middle of a product as single products span multiple lines.